# Seaborn 1D Heatmap switch x-and y-axis

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

Is it possible to switch the `x`- and `y` axis in a Seaborn 1D Heatmap?
The actual plot looks like:

[image: Actual Heatmap]

My code for this plot is as followed:

```
#Histogram data
n1, bins1, patches1 = plt.hist(x_start, bins=binwidth, cumulative=False, normed=1, facecolor='#023d6b', alpha=0.8, histtype='bar',label='density random')
n2, bins2, patches2 = plt.hist(histo, bins=binwidth, cumulative=False, normed=1, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, histtype='bar',label='density real')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Departure real': n2,'Departure model':n1},
               index= bins2[:-1]+1)

#Plot Options
fig2, ax2 =plt.subplots(figsize=(16,11))
ax2=sns.heatmap(df, annot=False, fmt="g",cmap="seismic",cbar_kws={'label': 'Probability'})
ax2.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(16)
ax2.set_ylabel('Hours [h]', fontsize=16)
ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=16)
ax2.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=16)
ax2.invert_yaxis()
cax = plt.gcf().axes[-1]
cax.tick_params(labelsize=16)
```

So at the end `Hours [h]` should be on the `x`-axis and `Departure model`, `Departure real` on the `y`-axis. I couldn't find any solution for that until now. I don't have to use Seaborn, if there is another method to do that better.

Comment: `sns.heatmap(df.T, ...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose the dataframe:

```
df=df.transpose()
```